# THREE.SmoothShading has no effect on geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

Smooth shading seems to have no effect on my model - the polygons are clearly visible and toggling between smooth and flat shading in the three.js inspector has no effect. There is vertex normal data in the obj so using geometry.computeVertexNormals() shouldn't be needed as has been suggested on a few other posts.

Using THREE.WebGLRenderer

Any leads appreciated :)

[obj,mtl,img files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0m1vmut1h4r6k3l/AACw0MH_z3cs6pcL00NM4DLGa?dl=0)

This is my loader function:

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
        mtlLoader.setBaseUrl(pathToLoad);
        mtlLoader.setPath(pathToLoad);                       
        mtlLoader.load('model_mesh.obj.mtl', function (materials) {
            materials.preload();
            var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
            objLoader.setPath(pathToLoad);
            objLoader.load('model_mesh.obj', function (obj) {
                obj.name = pathToLoad.substring(12, 17);
                testArray.push(obj);
                scene.add(obj);  
                loadNextPath(); 
            });
        });
```

[screenshot, polygons visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xbtL.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with your model. It has "flat" vertex normals.

[image]

If you don't want to fix your model, you can recompute smooth vertex normals by using a pattern like this one:

```
loader.load( 'model_mesh.obj', function( object ) {

    var mesh = object.children[ 0 ];

    mesh.geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( mesh.geometry );

    mesh.geometry.mergeVertices();

    mesh.geometry.computeVertexNormals();

    // convert back to BufferGeometry prior to rendering
    mesh.geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry( mesh.geometry );

    scene.add( object );

});
```

three.js r.95